# Facet skip value x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, axes, tidyr

Im working on this df:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("tidyr")
library("scales")
library("dplyr")


Col0 <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD","EE","FF")
D01012015 <- c(2,2,2,6,1,NA)
D02012015 <- c(2,2,2,1,3,1)
D03012015 <- c(2,2,3,4,6,4)
D04012015 <- c(2,2,3,1,2,4)
D05012015 <- c(2,1,1,1,1,0)
D06012015 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,9)
D07012015 <- c(2,4,2,5,4,1)
D08012015 <- c(2,2,3,4,5,3)
D09012015 <- c(1,3,3,2,2,1)
D10012015 <- c(1,3,3,2,2,1)
D11012015 <- c(1,3,3,2,4,1)
D12012015 <- c(1,3,3,4,2,1)
D13012015 <- c(1,3,5,2,2,1)
D14012015 <- c(1,3,3,7,2,1)
D15012015 <- c(1,3,3,7,2,7)

df<-data.frame(Col0,D01012015,D02012015,D03012015,D04012015,D05012015,D06012015,D07012015,D08012015,D09012015,D10012015,D11012015,
               D12012015,D13012015,D14012015,D15012015)
```

I know that normally, if i'd like to print a value per week on the x axis i should create this ggplot function:

```
f<-melt(df,id =c("Col0"))
f$date<-as.Date(f$variable, format="D%d%m%Y")
pl<- ggplot(f, aes(date, value, fill=Col0))+ geom_line(aes(color=Col0,group=Col0))+ scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 week"))
```

My problem is that i have to create the same x axis values, using this function:

```
plotfun = function(data) {

  xval<-"dates"
  column<- names(data)[1]  
  data %>%
    gather_(xval, "Val", select_vars_(names(.), 
                                      names(.), 
                                      exclude = column)) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(xval, "Val", group = column, col = column)) + 
    facet_grid(as.formula(paste(column, "~."))) + 
    geom_line() 
}

plotfun(df)
```

I don't know how to transform in dates the x values with gather and how to jump values as in the previous ggplot function

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example); your current code doesn't run in a new environment as not all packages are loaded.

Comment: @Heroka I edited the question adding the libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just put in a `mutate` statement?

```
plotfun <- function(data) {

  xval <- "dates"
  column <- names(data)[1]  
  data %>%
    gather_(xval, "Val", select_vars_(names(.), 
                                      names(.), 
                                      exclude = column)) %>% 
    mutate(dates = as.Date(f$variable, format = "D%d%m%Y")) %>%
    ggplot(aes_string(xval, "Val", group = column, col = column)) + 
    facet_grid(as.formula(paste(column, "~."))) + 
    geom_line() 
}

plotfun(df)
```